# How to change the name of the file during unzip?

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

I need to change the name of the file with current time or something else when unzipping, and need to save the file.

I know to unzip the file and saving using the function

```
unzip_file()
```

But I need to change the file name before save.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if($zip->open($path) === TRUE) {
   $name = $zip->getNameIndex(0);
   $zip->extractTo($destination);
   $zip->close();
}
$ext = pathinfo("/destination/$name", PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
rename("/destination/$name" . $ext, "/destination/$new_name" . $ext);
```